# Python: Dictionary with 3 items

Tags: python, text, hash

I have a file with 3 columns:

```
ArabicWord POS EnglishTranslation
```

Which is Arabic word, its POStag and the English translation of that Arabic word. So one Arabic word might have different translations according to different POS tags.
Now I want to store this file in a hash in Python. but my problem is that the entities of each column might occur more than once (no one is unique). One way of storing this file is concatenating the first and second column to make a unique entity (each Arabic word by a specific tag is allowed to have just one translation), but since I need hash to furthur processes, this way slows down the process.
Is there any other way?

*UPDATE:* 
The first approach works fine for storing the file. but my problem now is how to use these tuples. I can have access to the Arabic word and its pos tag by simply dict[0], dict[1] but how can I have access to the English translation?

Comment: Python dictionaries can take tuples as keys too: `words[ArabicWord, POS] = EnglishTranslation`? Or use a nested dict: `words[ArabicWord] = dict(); `words[ArabicWord][POS] = EnglishTranslation` (which is where `collections.defaultdict` could be helpful).

Comment: How about a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: I would go with the dictionary of tuples too, it shouldn't slow the process too much. It's still hashed.

Comment: How are you going to use that structure? For example, will there be queries like "find an arabic word by its english translation"?

Comment: I want to do some processes on the POS tag and translation of each Arabic word. for example the number of the translations of each Arabic word.

Comment: dear Martijn Pieters, the first approach works fine for storing the file. but my problem now is how to use these tuples. I can have access to the Arabic word and its pos tag by simply dict[0], dict[1] but how can I have access to the English translation?

Comment: @Hakim you can use `get` method like: `words.get((arabicWord, POS))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments on your question, I would use a dictionary of dictionaries:

Defining the data structure:

```
>>> words = { 'ArabicWord' : { 'POS1' : 'EnglishTranslation1' } }
>>> words['ArabicWord']['POS2'] = 'EnglishTranslation2'
>>> words
{'ArabicWord': {'POS2': 'EnglishTranslation2', 'POS1': 'EnglishTranslation1'}}
```

Finding all the POS tags for a specific Arabic word:

```
>>> words['ArabicWord'].keys()
['POS2', 'POS1']
```

Finding the English translation for a specific ArabicWord/POS tag combination:

```
>>> words['ArabicWord']['POS1']
'EnglishTranslation1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an in-memory [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) database. This will allow you to continue to work with the data as three distinct columns, and it's easy to fetch whatever data you need.

Comment: I dont want to make it this much complicated. I actually need a very simple way to do this. because I don't want to do many processes.

Comment: A sqlite database isn't very complicated and doesn't require any other processes. It's extremely fast and lightweight. I think you would be surprised at how simple it can be.